# Is there a way to fly an UAV over a roadway?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

With an FAA Section 333 Exemption, they will permit you to fly up to 400' above ground level. But they also restrict you to flying at least 500' away from people and vehicles unless you have their permission. You can't get permission from every vehicle driver that happens to be passing by. Does this effectively mean that there is absolutely no way to fly over a public roadway, or is there another exception or reasoning to be able to do this?

Comment: Wait for traffic to die down? (Depends on the roadway, of course...)

Comment: The regulations are put in place to protect the people on the ground. Consider what can happen if your UAV became uncontrollable - loss of power, impact with power lines, a bird, etc - and impacted the roadway or a car. You could cause a major accident. Your drone causes a car traveling 30 MPH to swerve into a telephone pole, killing the driver or a pedestrian. Do you want to take that risk? I think that is the real question, not how to get an exemption.

Answer (score 5):

For certain operations the FAA does grant waivers to [14 CFR § 91.119(b)](http://rgl.faa.gov/regulatory_and_guidance_library/rgfar.nsf/farsbysectlookup/91.119) and/or [(c)](http://rgl.faa.gov/regulatory_and_guidance_library/rgfar.nsf/farsbysectlookup/91.119). These waivers are generally granted for the purpose of allowing pipeline or powerline patrol, aerial survey, or for other operations that are in the public interest. The waivers are also generally granted to the operators of certified or restricted category aircraft, not UAS.

If you represent an operation for which a waiver would be in the public's interest and can demonstrate that the operation would be conducted safely, you might qualify for a waiver.

However, even for that waiver, you have to demonstrate strong evidence to gain a minimum distance of less than 500 feet:

> [3-185 A.](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/8900.1/v03%20tech%20admin/chapter%2007/03_007_001.pdf) Unless it is necessary to
>   safeguard human life or it can be determined to be in the public interest and contributing to the public health, welfare, and safety, the 500-foot minimum separation distance from persons on the surface shall not be waived.

Note that 14 CFR § 91.119(a) and (d) are never to be waived.

See [this document](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/8900.1/v03%20tech%20admin/chapter%2007/03_007_001.pdf) for more information on the above discussed waiver.

---

Now, all that being said, I don't know if the above example of a waiver apples directly to your question or not; perhaps 91.119 is not the regulation that you were concerned about. Regardless, that waiver is an example of what can be worked out.

The current UAS issue is uncharted water for the FAA; there may or may not be precedent for an operation or exemption. Bottom line, if you have a really good reason to do the operation you want to do, you might be able to work it out with the FAA. Otherwise, you will have to stick to the rules as they are.